# Simple test program using sscanf does not work

Tags: c, scanf

I was wondering why the following does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nbytes = 100;
    char* string;
    string = malloc((sizeof(char) * nbytes) + 1); 
    int x, y, z;
    int args_assigned = 0;

    while (args_assigned != 3)
    {
        printf("Please enter three integers separated by whitespace\n"
        scanf("%s", string);
        args_assigned = sscanf(string, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    }

    free(string);
    printf("Thanks for %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

In the original version of this code, the programmer had used `getline` instead of `scanf`, but apparently this is no longer a valid function in C99? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Anyway, I suspect the problem is to do with my use of `scanf`. Is there another function I should be using to provide the string for `sscanf` to parse? Of course, there could be something far more fundamental that I am missing here...

Comment: There has never been a `getline` function in standard C.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't read lines. In particular, `%s` reads a (whitespace separated) word.

Comment: `getline()` is a C++ funcction. The analogous function in C is `fgets()`.

Comment: you should limit the length of the string you read. `sizeof(char)` is defined to yield `1`. That will never differ, so it is useless.

Answer (score 4):

You ask the user to enter three integers separated by spaces.

You try to read that information with `"%s"` which stops reading at the first space.  This is why you run into problems.  You could have found this out by printing what you get from your `scanf()` call.

Don't forget to check the return value from `sscanf()`.

There is a POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which reads a whole line and tells you how long it is.  Alternatively, there is the standard C function `fgets()` which can be used to read whole lines.

At a pinch, you could use `scanf(" %[^\n]", string)`, but I really wouldn't recommend it; use `getline()` or `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

To read a line of input, use `fgets()`.

```
fgets(string, nbytes + 1, stdin);
```

Comment: Hi thanks! fgets(string, nbytes, stdin) does work. Previously I had tried:

Comment: previously I had tried fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) and fgets(string, strlen(string), stdin), but neither of these worked. Why would this be? Thanks again

Comment: `string` is a pointer, so `sizeof (string)` is the size of the pointer (probably 4 bytes), not the size of the buffer you allocated. And `strlen(string)` is the length of the current value in the string (the position of the terminating null), which is undefined because you haven't put anything into it yet.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks again... btw, do you know if there is a limit to how many "novice" questions you can ask on here? It seems my reputation has gone down after this latest post...

Comment: Your rep went down because of the downvotes. Why people downvoted, I don't know.

Comment: @Matthew2015: there's no direct limit on the number of novice questions; your reputation won't go negative (or go to zero).  OTOH, you probably want to get to a decent positive reputation, if only so you can leave comments (50 points needed, IIRC).  Post compilable code (what you showed won't compile — as pointed out in one answer). Try to avoid asking what seem like obvious questions (by doing things like basic debugging by printing out the value read in, or knowing how to run a debugger and looking at what is read — which would show you what's going on) would help too. Know your manual, too.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to finish this line:

```
printf("Please enter three integers separated by whitespace\n"
```

Comment: That's obviously a copying error, not the problem he's having. This should be a comment, not an answer.